# How to configure phpunit with Netbeans 8.1? "Cannot open file vendor/autoload.php" while testing class

Tags: php, netbeans, phpunit

I got error while testing class in Netbeans:

> Cannot open file
>   "C:\wamp\www\Calculator-PHPUnit2\test../vendor/autoload.php".

[image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Netbeans sample project named "Calculator - PHPUnit Sample Application" generates phpunit.xml with line
`<phpunit bootstrap="../vendor/autoload.php">`